# Change the size of chart dynamic regarding the size of data frame and modify the format of X axis in plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, streamlit

I wrote the code below and it works fine for a scatter plot.

I want to modify the code as I want to show year in the format **July 2010**, currently it is 10-01, also I want to show all the date (yesr and month) and not part of it.

The size of chart has to be dynamic, because sometimes regarding what is checked in the streamlit app, the final data frame Data is bigger or smaller, meaning  in the CODE, sometimes I select one code, sometime I select 50 code in Y axis or some times I  have one year (only for example 2011), sometime I have from 2010 to 2020 ,so the size I want to be dynamic regarding the size of dataframe, do you have any idea?

````
color_discrete_map = {'df1': 'rgb(255,0,0)',
                      'df2': 'rgb(0,255,0)',
                      'df3': '#11FCE4',
                      'df4': '#9999FF',
                      'df5': '#606060',
                      'df6': 'CC6600'}


fig = px.scatter(df, x='DATE', y='CODE', color='DATA', width=1200,
                 height=600,color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)

fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(l=250, r=0, t=0, b=20),

)
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickformat="%y-%m"))

fig.update_xaxes(ticks= "outside",
                 ticklabelmode= "period", 
                 tickcolor= "black", 
                 ticklen=10, 
                 minor=dict(
                     ticklen=4,  
                     dtick=7*24*60*60*1000,  
                     tick0="2016-07-03", 
                     griddash='dot', 
                     gridcolor='white')
                )

st.plotly_chart(fig) ```
````

Comment: It would help if you explain clearer what your Streamlit app does and how data is selected (is df updated on selecting dataframe rows? something else?).
You can change the label format with tickformat, as you already set it. See the docs for the exact datetime format string.

Comment: yes regarding a few filter the size of data frame changes on the row. Columns are always fixed!.

Comment: when the row changes it has direct affect on the y axis and x axis, the year range and code range can be huge or few.

Comment: Just specify the limit of the x axis using `fig.update_xaxes(range=[MINVALUE, MAXVALUE])`, with MINVALUE and MAXVALUE being read before that from your updated dataframe row.